# Print function doesnt return anything

Tags: python, function, printing

In python I have the code below, it goes through the process flawlessly but after entering in the color selection and meeting the parameters the print function returns nothing. For instance when I run the code I enter red as primary 1 and blue as primary 2 it should print the function of secondary color is purple but it does not do this, am I missing something? I am using the web based version of python from online-python.com if that matters.

```
red = '1'
blue = '2'
yellow = '3'
prime_1 = input('Enter your first primary color: ')
prime_2 = input('Enter your second primary color: ')
if prime_1 == 1 and prime_2 == 2:
    print ("Your secondary color is purple!")
```

Tried entering red and blue as the primary colors to print out "purple" however after entering the colors the print function doesnt return anything.

Comment: `input` returns a string since Python 3, so comparison with an integer always fails. Try having the numbers as strings, or interpreting the input as an integer using `int()`.

Comment: If you are actually entering the strings `red` and `blue`, why do you have numbers at all? You can, e.g., set `red = "red"`, and compare `prime_1` and `red` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass the color, e.g., blue and red as your input because, you are comparing two integers. For it to print purple, first enclose the 1 and 2 in the if statement with quotation marks, then pass them as inputs to your program as it runs.
Also the declared variables are not necessary for this script. You can remove them.

Here is an example:

```
prime_1 = input('Enter your first primary color: ')
prime_2 = input('Enter your second primary color: ')
if prime_1 == '1' and prime_2 == '2':
    print("Your secondary color is purple!")
```